How to Implement Auto-Printing Without Print Dialog for a Web Application?
I am developing a web application where I need to automatically print a specific part of the page (div with id="printableArea") when a user submits a form. Here's the relevant HTML and JavaScript.
Currently, this code triggers the browser's print dialog. However, for this specific feature, I need to bypass the print dialog and print directly to the default printer without any user interaction.
I understand that browsers generally restrict silent printing for security reasons, but this feature is intended for a controlled environment (e.g., a point-of-sale system in a restaurant) where such functionality is crucial.
**html form
**
  <form action="{{ route('vendor.pos.order') }}?restaurant_id={{ isset($restaurant_data) ? $restaurant_data-       >id : '' }}"
    id='order_place' method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="customer_id">
    <div class="box p-3">
       
        <div class="row button--bottom-fixed g-1 bg-white">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" class="btn  btn--primary btn-sm btn-block">{{ translate('place_order') }}
                </button>
            </div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
</form>`

<div id="printableArea">Hello world</div>

**javascipt **
 function printDiv(divName) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }


It might be possible to do with a specific preconfigured browser - see for example this answer for Firefox
